# Invalidate GradientDrawable

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, reset

I have the following xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@color/color_primary_dark" />
    <size android:width="25dp" android:height="25dp" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/white" />

</shape>
```

And at some point in my application I change the color of this shape like this:

```
// priority_button has this shape as is src
(priority_button.drawable as GradientDrawable).setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_orange_light))
```

The problem is: if I destroy the activity and then re-open the same activity, this shape stays with the last color that I set (in this case android.R.color.holo_orange_light) and I want to that shape reset to the same color that is defined in the xml (R.color.color_primary_dark).

Since I am setting the color programmatically I think that I am changing the xml itself and when the activity is re-opened, and the views are draw, it gets the xml that I set another color.

Is any way to reset the xml values or something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try invoking `mutate()` on the `drawable` before changing its color.

As per [setColor(int argb)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setColor(int)) documentation it states that:

> changing color will affect all instances of a drawable loaded from a resource. It is recommended to invoke mutate() before changing the color.

So maybe this affects you as well.

Comment: This is the most useful comment on stack. I dunno why people who recommend this way of changing stroke color didn't mention this. I lost 3 hours for this.